# Compare a nested list to a column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to compare the maximum value from a nested list (the values are extracted from the text in this list) versus a number (not nested) in another column and gsub elements in the nested list based on this comparison:P

***Input:***

```
structure(list(ExtentNumber = list("3", 1, "2", 
    "4", "1"), BiopsyType = list("2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 2", 
    c("4--Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum Number of biopsies: 7", 
    "2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 9", "Biopsy site: None", 
    "3--Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb Number of biopsies: 1"), c("1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 10", 
    "2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 6"), "3--Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb Number of biopsies: 4", 
    c("1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 6", "4--Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum Number of biopsies: 9"
    ))), .Names = c("ExtentNumber", "BiopsyType"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

***Initally I tried:***

```
lapply(OGDProcedureDf$BiopsyType, function(p)
  ifelse(max(as.numeric(str_match(p,"^(\\d)--")),na.rm=T)>OGDProcedureDf$ExtentNumber,gsub("*.","",p),p)
  )
```

but realised that I was comparing to all the numbers in `ExtentNumber`
Then I tried wrapping this in an apply function as follows:

```
apply(OGDProcedureDf,1,function(x)  lapply(OGDProcedureDf$BiopsyType, function(p)
  ifelse(max(as.numeric(str_match(p,"^(\\d)--")),na.rm=T)>OGDProcedureDf$ExtentNumber,gsub("*.","",p),p)
  ))
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

So basically how can I find and replace elements in a nested list based on a column value that is not nested?

***Expected outcome:***

```
structure(list(ExtentNumber = list("3", 1, "2", "4", "1"), BiopsyType = list("2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 2", 
                                                                c("", "", ""), c("1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 10","")
                                                                , "3--Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb Number of biopsies: 4", 
                                                                c("1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 6", ""
                                                                ))), .Names = c("ExtentNumber", "BiopsyType"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @Sotos I have added this now

Comment: what is the idea to obtain the result?

Comment: You are missing the df as first argument, `apply(1,function(x) etc)` needs **a first argument** as in `apply(to_this_df, 1,function(x) etc)`.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas. I have amended. But even with that I don't get the desired output- it just crashes.

Comment: I don't understand your outcome...

Comment: @Sotos- basically for each row, if the number in the ExtentNumber column is < the number of an element in the BiopsyType colmn then the element in BiopsyType should be erased.

Comment: oh you mean this number... `**number**--Biopsy Site:.....`?

Comment: @Sotos yes as defined in the regular expression

Comment: I m finding some inconsistencies with your expected output. Here is what I did so far. Note the output shows which *'words'* to return, so If all is FALSE like row 2, then nothing will be returned. Try this `Map(function(x, y) replace(x > y, is.na(x > y), FALSE) , df$ExtentNumber, lapply(df$BiopsyType, function(i) as.numeric(gsub('^([0-9]+)--.*$', '\\1', i))))`. Try it and let me know

Comment: @Sotos yes that works. Can you post as an answer. I guess the gsub goes where the FALSE is in your expression

Comment: @Sotos I get true and false here. How can I get the actual phrase instead if it is TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Map(function(x,y)y[as.numeric(x)>=as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+).*$|.*","\\1",y))],
                        dat$ExtentNumber,dat$BiopsyType)
[[1]]
[1] "2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 2"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 10" "2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 6"    

[[4]]
[1] "3--Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb Number of biopsies: 4"

[[5]]
[1] "1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 6"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but here is a follow up of my comments,

```
l1 <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x > y, is.na(x > y), FALSE) , 
                                                df$ExtentNumber, 
                                                lapply(df$BiopsyType, function(i) 
                                                      as.numeric(gsub('^([0-9]+)--.*$', '\\1', i))))

mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x[y], collapse = ', '), 
                                 lapply(df$BiopsyType, function(i) unlist(strsplit(i, ', '))), l1)

#[1] "2--Biopsy site: Stomach Number of biopsies: 2"   ""   "1--Biopsy site: Oesophagus Number of biopsies: 10"   "3--Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb Number of biopsies: 4"
#[5] ""
```